# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ibatis.common.beans.ClassInfo.setCacheEnabled(Z)V

Tags: java, eclipse, ibatis

I'm tryin a desktop application using iBatis. But I got following error.Was not able to find a proper solution on net.Please any one help me out.

Logs::

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ibatis.common.beans.ClassInfo.setCacheEnabled(Z)V
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.builder.xml.SqlMapConfigParser$3.process(SqlMapConfigParser.java:179)
at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.processNodelet(NodeletParser.java:112)
at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.process(NodeletParser.java:75)
at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.process(NodeletParser.java:93)
at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.parse(NodeletParser.java:63)
at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.parse(NodeletParser.java:51)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.builder.xml.SqlMapConfigParser.parse(SqlMapConfigParser.java:86)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapClientBuilder.buildSqlMapClient(SqlMapClientBuilder.java:63)
at IbatisInsert.main(IbatisInsert.java:12)
```

Codes ::IbatisInsert.java

```
import com.ibatis.common.resources.Resources;
import com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapClient;
import com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapClientBuilder;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.*;

public class IbatisInsert{
  public static void main(String[] args)
   throws IOException,SQLException{
   Reader rd = Resources.getResourceAsReader("SqlMapConfig.xml");
   SqlMapClient smc = SqlMapClientBuilder.buildSqlMapClient(rd);

   /* This would insert one record in Employee table. */
   System.out.println("Going to insert record.....");
   Employee em = new Employee("Zara", "Ali", 5000);

   smc.insert("Employee.insert", em);

   System.out.println("Record Inserted Successfully ");

  }
}
```

Employee.java

```
public class Employee {
      private int id;
      private String first_name; 
      private String last_name;   
      private int salary;  

      /* Define constructors for the Employee class. */
      public Employee() {}

      public Employee(String fname, String lname, int salary) {
        this.setFirst_name(fname);
        this.setLast_name(lname);
        this.setSalary(salary);
      }

    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }

    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    } /* End of Employee */
```

I have put both class in default package under src.

Comment: Looks like a jar conflict issue. The code is compiled with some other version of iBatis and running on some other version.

Comment: I'm new to ibatis,what all jars do I need. I have following jars :: 1>ibatis-commons-2.jar 2>ibatis-2.3.0.677.jar 3>spring.jar 4>mysql-connector-java-5.1.5.JAR

Comment: @AbhijeetSinha the problem is not due to insufficient jars but incorrect version of jars. I have given code below try running it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with classloading/classpath. Try using this code in your main class and find out the path from where your jar is being loaded.

Maybe the jar you are loading is incorrect version.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            URLClassLoader classLoader = (URLClassLoader)IbatisInsert.class.getClassLoader();
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(classLoader.getURLs()));
    }
```

Comment: maybe the ClassLoader is picking up the jar from some other place. Above code will give you all the paths from where the dependencies have been resolved.